# C++: Copy a file to the root directory under Windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I wonder whether it is possible in C++ to programatically copy a concrete file to the root directory. For example, say I have a file exm.txt in the location C:\example\ and I'd like to copy it to C:\ so that I'll obtain a file C:\exm.txt. Is it possible in C++ WinAPI? When using

```
CopyFile("C:\\example\\exm.txt","C:\\exm.txt",true);
```

nothing happens and this functions returns error code 5: Access denied [I'm almost sure I'm working as the administrator - this is my personal computer].
The aforementioned function - as far as I know - works correctly for all other directories (different from the root directory in some partition). So, my question is whether we can do programatically copy also to the root directory.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: did you run the application with adminiatrator privilege? (right click and run as admin).

Comment: Ok, I found a solution: it suffices to set in the executable c++ file the option: run as an administrator - then it is possible to copy from and into root directories.

Comment: You have read access in the root directory of the system volume. You have write access to files there. What you don't have rights to do, as standard user, is to create files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because the security settings, by default, do not allow standard user to create files at the root level of the system drive.

The obvious solutions are:

1. Save the file somewhere else if you can. It's good practise not to litter the root directory of the system volume.
2. Run the process with elevated rights by adding the `requireAdministrator` option to your manifest. Or by right clicking the executable or shortcut and selecting *Run as administrator*.